# Adding collection routes to nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to add some collection routes for a nested resource. I have a subscription controller and I need two new methods to add here. `change_plan` and `update_plan`

Basically I need the urls looks like;

```
http://localhost:3007/admin/accounts/1/subscriptions/7/change_plan
http://localhost:3007/admin/accounts/1/subscriptions/7/update_plan
```

So where to add change_plan and update_plan? this is what I have so far.

```
 map.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.resources :payments
    admin.resources :accounts, :collection=>{:profile=>:get}, :has_many => [:payments,:subscriptions]
```

end

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the alternative syntax for `has_many`:

```
admin.resources :accounts, :collection=>{:profile=>:get} do |account|
  account.resources :subscriptions, :member => { :change_plan => :get, ... }
  ...
end
```

Comment: That worked pretty well Marcel, thanks a bunch. I'll mark it as the answer.